# How to check for symbols in EditText in android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a EditText in android where IP Address is supposed to be entered. On click of a button I want to check if the text retrieved from EditText does :

- not have any spaces
- not have any letters
- not empty
- contain only numbers
- and contain only periods `"."`

I have this if else condition to check if the user is allowed to go to the next activity but it still has some bugs. I don't know how to allow ONLY periods

```
                    if(((ip.length() != 0) || ip.contains(" ") == false || ip.matches("[a-z]+") == false) && (ip.matches("[0-9]+") && ip.contains(".")))
                    {
                        next = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        next = true;
                    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex to check the input

```
"^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$"
```

EDIT:

Do not use regex as things will break when IPv6 comes, use this instead

http://commons.apache.org/validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/InetAddressValidator.html

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple with Regular Expression

> ```
> private static final String PATTERN = 
>     "^([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +
>     "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +
>     "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +
>     "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])$";
>
>  public static boolean validate(final String ip){          
>
>   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(PATTERN);
>   Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(ip);
>   return matcher.matches();             
>   }
> ```

I hope it will help you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
<EditText
    android:inputType="number"
    android:digits="0123456789."
/>
```

allowing only `numbers and .`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this much elegant by using [android.util.Patterns](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Patterns.html):

```
import android.util.Patterns
...
boolean isIPvalid (String input) {
    return Patterns.IP_ADDRESS.matcher(input).matches();
}
```